# Sorting List of Strings by last 2 characters

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a basic question on string sorting with last 2 characters of the string. Here's the list of input strings and sorted list of strings based on last 2 characters. I used MySQL query to sort. But I could not logically explain why strings are sorted in that fashion.

Input Strings:

```
ksalan
isalan
rsalan
bsalan
```

Sorted List:

```
rsalan
isalan
ksalan
bsalan
```

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

If you sort by last two characters then from sorter's point of view all the strings are equal.  The order of rows produced by select is not guaranteed, it may depend on many factors (order in which strings were inserted, primary key, indexes created etc.)

So, rows are selected and then sort is applied to them. As all rows should have identical position it is up to internally implemented algorithm how to return them.